# A sequential problem with 2 different methods

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am learning something sequence related and here's what the book says:

> S = 1 + 5^2 + 5^3... + 5^99 + 5^100
> 5S = 5 + 5^2 + 5^3... + 5^100 + 5^101
>
> 5S - S = 4S
> 4S = 5^101 -1
> S = (5^101 - 1)/4
>
> The method is called Method of Differences, now try to apply the method to: 1 + 1/2 + (1/2)^2...(1/2)^2022

Then I started trying out:

Step 1 : A = 1 + 1/2 + (1/2)^2...(1/2)^2022 # old sequence
Step 2 : 1/2A = 1/2 + (1/2)^2...(1/2)^2023 # new sequence
Step 3 : 1/2A - A = -1/2A
                    -1/2A = (1/2)^2023 + 1
                            A = (1/2)^2023 * -2

Then I checked up the answer, I found my answer was incorrect (I still don't know where I am getting wrong) and something very confusing:

> the answer said you should do the A - 1/2A instead,or you can do 2A - A.

For A - 1/2A, shouldn't we use the new sequence subtracting the old one? Why it is in reverse?

For 2A - A, yes this is the right order but why 2A? Isn't supposed to be the common ratio which is 1/2?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{2022}}$. Multiplying throughout by $\frac{1}{2}$ gives $\frac{A}{2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{2023}}$.
Subtract the second expression from the first. That gives
\begin{gather}
A-\frac{A}{2}=(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{2022}})-(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{2023}})\\
\frac{A}{2}=1-\frac{1}{2^{2023}}\\
A=2-\frac{1}{2^{2022}}
\end{gather}
You made a mistake in the step where you subtracted $A$ from $\frac{A}{2}$. The right-hand side must have been $\frac{1}{2^{2023}}-1$ instead of $\frac{1}{2^{2023}}+1$.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to get most of the terms to cancel out.  This occurs whether you multiply or divide the original sequence by 2.  In this case, 2A-A has the advantage that you can eliminate a step of division.

It doesn't make the method you attempted incorrect.  So let's correct it.  First of all, don't write "1/2A".  It makes it look like $\frac1{2A}$.  "A/2" is much clearer.  When you subtract $\frac A2$ from $A$, you're left with the $\dfrac1{2^{2023}}$ term from $\frac A2$ and the $1$ term from $A$.  Since $A$ was the term you subtracted, the 1 term that came from $A$ should have a minus sign, so you should have $$-\frac A2=\dfrac1{2^{2023}}-1$$.

The next mistake came when multiplying by $-2$.  The minus sign never got distributed.  If we multiply by $-2$ from here we get

$$A=-2(\dfrac1{2^{2023}}-1)=-\dfrac1{2^{2022}}+2$$